# Set up a UISearchDisplayController for a UITableViewController without a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I find that the only way to build a `UISearchDisplayController` is to also build a `UISearchBar` onto my `UITableViewController`.

However, I don't want a `UISearchBar` to show up, and would like to initiate the search via a button press instead.

Is this possible?

I tried activating the `UISearchDisplayController` on button press:

```
- (void)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
  [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This "works", but the `searchDisplayController` that shows up has no `UISearchBar`. (Obviously).

Comment: A `UISearchDisplayController` is specifically written to use a `UISearchBar`. If you don't have a search bar don't use a `UISearchDisplayController`. What kind of UI do you have that allows for a search without the user entering any search criteria?

Comment: Well when the UISearchDisplayController shows up, I _do_ want to show a searchBar (which is the problem I am having right now). I just don't want the search bar to be present if the UISearchDisplayController isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just setting the `hidden` field to NO and YES when the search display controller is shown and dismissed.